# Setting and retrieving custom HTTP header in Rails Monolithic App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have rails login page and after user authentication I am trying to generate JWT token(rather than using the session ID) for authorization the next subsequent request.

I have set the custom header in response and redirecting the request in next page.

```
response.headers["access_token"] = "token"
```

How can I get those headers in rails controller?

To me this task seems impossible as server is sending some custom header in response but client/browser is not sending/appending custom header in the subsequent request.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: > client/browser is not sending/appending any header in the request back.    Why not? This is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: A server can not decide what headers the client will respond with. Thats kind of the point of  cookies which basically ask the client to pass them back. You're asking two different questions of which one is based on a premise thats broken.

Comment: @Joel_Blum, i have updated my question.  '> client/browser is not sending/appending custom header in the request back'

Comment: This question can't be answered without the actual client side code in question.

Comment: @max, I am using plain html, there is no client side code. I want to handle everything from rails server only.

Comment: You can't actually send headers from links or forms in a browser. That requires an XHR request (as in javascript). What you want is most likely classical cookie based authentication (aka sessions).

Comment: Links just send a request for the URI along with the standard headers like User-Agent, Accept-Type and Referrer. Forms send along a request body in addition. I doubt you want to append your access tokens to every link/form in your application.

Comment: @max, right now we are using cookie based authentication but in our monolithic app, we implemented some of the modules  which are in react/angularjs which is using APIs but APIs are also getting authenticated by session only. 
But we want to separate out authentication mechanism for API from session to token based and also slowly want to convert our rails monolithic app into micro-services. 
I want to to create a separate service for authentication/authorization but seems difficult task until we move our app into rails API based app.
Any help how should I proceed further in right direction.

Comment: You really need a two pronged approach where you keep sessions for the monolithic app and then faze them out on your API. Warden is a pretty good example at how you can use multiple authentication strategies like sessions, http basic and tokens  in the same app.